# Angularjs filter unordered list

Tags: list, angularjs, static, filter, listitem

I'm trying to filter strings in a static unordered list. I'm able to filter items in an array but not sure how to do it for static html content.

The way I've learned to achieve it using an array is by using this method:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="name" />

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:name">
    {{ person }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to achieve the same effect using an existing `<ul>`

```
<input type="search" ng-model="filter.name" placeholder="filter..." />

<ul>
   <li><a href="#bob">Bob</a>/li>
   <li><a href="#lisa">Lisa</a></li>
   <li><a href="#lewis">Lewis</a></li>
   <li><a href="#xuemin">Xuemin</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tom">Tom</a></li>
   <li><a href="#cassidy">Cassidy</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to filter the list items based on the text strings inside them, so for example typing 'L' in the textbox would only show:

- Lisa
- Lewis

Comment: If the <li> elements are not dynamically created with ng-repeat you can't filter them easily with angular. You could user jQuery, or straight javascript to achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a hacked out way of doing it [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/uGG98/).

The key to it is in ng-change="filter()". Every time you enter a letter you decide which elements to show or hide.

```
$scope.filter = function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('list');
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.children.length; i++) {
        var name = elem.children[i].children[0].innerHTML;
        if (name.indexOf($scope.name) != -1 || $scope.name == "") {
              elem.children[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            elem.children[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, it's an ugly hack, but it works. You would be better off making an object out of your names, and using ng-repeat.

Comment: This is an impressive hack, and probably demonstrates how Angular may be the wrong tool for the job here. I agree with you the names should be objects unfortunately this isn't an option with the project I'm working with and would require a massive overhaul. For this case it may be better to use your previous suggestion and use jQuery. Thanks for your help.

Comment: which angularjs version?